# Linux using a method from a jar file (Java Code)

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to write a program that prints out a statement through Linux. The catch is that most of the statement must come from a method from a jar file. Basically. my code looks like this

```
public class identification {
     public static void main(String[] args){ // Main method with print statement
          System.out.print("I am " + person()); 
    } 
}
```

The person() method comes from the jar file. It should give something like "I am bob on a computer," but I can't quite figure out how to set up the CLASSPATH environment variable in the .bash_profile so it reads the method from the jar file. Any ideas? I am sure this is a simple task.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Class names should start with a capital letter -> **I**dentification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `cp` command to add a jar file

```
java -cp lib/myJar.jar myPackage.Program
```

also I believe you may need to `import` class where method `person` is in. I don't know how your hierarchy is so I can't help you with that.

Comment: If `person()` is static then you can use: `import ClassFromJar;` and `ClassFromJar.person()`. If it is non static you need the same import and do `ClassFromJar instance = new ClassFromJar(...);` and `instance.person()`.

Comment: Is the myPackage.Program the name of the jar plus the name of the program that is going to run?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jar to your classpath like this:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/your/myJar.jar
```

Comment: Note that this will set a global classpath which might be used by other Java applications. Not a good idea.